# How to get FAQ on a website working without using classnames?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to fix this accordion on a FAQ page. The question should open up the p tag with the answer when you click the h3 tag. Unfortunately it is not possible to use any class name or anything like that. Our client can now simply add a h3 and a p tag to create a new question. I'm trying to open up one question a the time. Somebody who can help me with this?

```
<style>
.faq h3{ background: #e2001a; color: #fff; padding: 5px 10px; cursor: 
pointer; user-select: none;}


.show {
display: block;
}
</style>

<div class="faq">
<h1>FAQ</h1>

<h3>Question 1</h3>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

 <h3>Question 2</h3>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

 <h3>Question 3</h3>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName(".faq h3");
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName(".faq p");

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('active');
    setClass(acc, 'active', 'remove');
    setClass(panel, 'show', 'remove');

    if (setClasses) {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
}

 function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].classList[fnName](className);
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why isn't it possible to use class names?

Comment: Our client can now simply add a h3 and a p tag to create a new question in our CMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) to target the paragraph of each clicked `h3`.

```js
// Grab all the h3s and paras
const h3s = document.querySelectorAll('h3');
const paras = document.querySelectorAll('p');

// Add click listeners to each h3
h3s.forEach(h3 => h3.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false));

function handleClick() {

  // Grab the nextElementSibling from the clicked element
  const { nextElementSibling: next } = this;

  // Remove all `show` classes from the paras
  paras.forEach(para => para.classList.remove('show'));

  // Add a show class to the sibling para
  next.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
p {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq">
<h1>FAQ</h1>

<h3>Question 1</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<h3>Question 2</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<h3>Question 3</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some small mistakes in your selectors. In **[getElementsByClassName('name')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** the name has to be a simple string (the class *name*), but you can look for child nodes with **[getElementsByTagName('name')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)** - for example.

If you want to use CSS selectors use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead:

```
var acc = document.querySelectorAll("div.faq > h3");
var panel = document.querySelectorAll('div.faq > p');
```

This example is using getElementsByClassName and getElementsByTagName:

```js
var faq = document.getElementsByClassName("faq")[0];
var acc = faq.getElementsByTagName('h3');
var panel =  faq.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var setClasses = !this.classList.contains("active");
    setClass(acc, "active", "remove");
    setClass(panel, "show", "remove");

    if (setClasses) {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
  };
}

function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].classList[fnName](className);
  }
}
```

```css
.faq h3 { 
  background: #e2001a; 
  color: #fff; 
  padding: 5px 10px; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  user-select: none;
}

.faq p {
  display: none;
}
.faq p.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq">
  <h1>FAQ</h1>
  <h3>Question 1</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

   <h3>Question 2</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

   <h3>Question 3</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!